# Envio fichero por SFTP en Linux mediante Groovy

Tags: linux, apache, groovy, sftp

Estoy intentando mandar un fichero csv mediante SFTP usando un script de groovy pero encuentra en las librerías de Apache que tiene el proyecto `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;`.

He pensado que puede haber otra manera de mandar ese fichero mediante comandos Linux integrados en el script pero no encuentro nada que me pueda valer de ejemplo.

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=use+sftp+for+transfer+files

Answer (score 0):

Para eso necesitas tener primero tu par de claves rsa.

Luego tienes que tener acceso a ese servidor, osea, tienes que tener le nombre del usuario remoto al que tienes acceso, y la dirección IP. Por ejemplo, "Bufank85@134.2.34.23". Y trata de ver si puedes realizar una conexión de SSH:

```
$ ssh <usuario remoto>@<ip remota>
```

Si puedes hacerlo, entonces puedes aplicar varias estrategias para subir un archivo desde tu compu local, al servidor remoto:

### scp

Este es el comando que más uso:

```
$ scp <ruta local> <usuario remoto>@<ip remota>:<ruta remota>
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ scp /home/cuau/memes.tar.gz cuau-remoto@23.34.54.31:/home/cuau-remoto/
```

### rsync

Es casi mismo que el ejemplo anterior, pero con el comando `rsync`

```
$ rsync <ruta local> <usuario remoto>@<ip remota>:<ruta remota>
```

### ssh

Esto sólo lo he usado en casos super específicos cuando quiero hacer streaming de un archivo:

```
$ cat <ruta del archivo> | ssh <usuario remoto>@<ip remota> "dd of=<dirección remota>"
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat /home/cuau/memes.mp4 | ssh cuau-remoto@39.23.12.5 "dd of=/home/cuau-remoto/memes.mp4"
```

### sftp

Este comando lo sé usar de forma interactiva. No sé si exista una forma tan sólo con la pura línea de comandos en bash:

```
$ sftp <usuario remoto>@<ip remoto>
sftp> put <archivo local a subir>
sftp> exit
```

Aquí "sftp>" es el prompt que indica que estamos en modo interactivo. Los comandos importantes solo son `put` y `exit`.

Ejemplo:

```
$ sftp cuau-remoto@34.5.2.5
sftp> put /home/cuau-local/memes.tar.gz
sftp> exit
```

Y te debe aparecer en la terminal el lugar donde se guardó. Algo como:

```
Output
Uploading local-file to /home/cuau-remoto/memes.tar.gz
```

La única manera que se me ocurre que podamos hacer esto en un one-liner para que no sea interactivo, es:

```
$ sftp <usuario remoto>@<ip remota> <<< 'put <ruta del archivo local>'
```

Y referente a tu script de groovy, yo he corrido script de groovy para pipelines de Jenkins de la siguiente manera:

```
sh "<comando de bash>"
```

Me parece que, después de configurar tu par de claves al servidor remoto, los comandos que te puse te podrían servir.